# how to call radcombobox selectedIndex changed event from page load

Tags: c#, .net, telerik

How can I call the `SelectedIndexChanged` event on Page Load?

My function looks like :

```
protected void ddlItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
```

How to pass for `RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs` `e` on page load?

Please suggest me.

Comment: Why do you want to call in page load? Does the event fire when you change the combobox?

Comment: Yes, event fires when I change in combo box

Comment: SelectedIndexChanged is an event type that will only fire when the combo box index changes. The code to handle this event shouldn't be in Page_Load. Please update and include more detail so we can give you a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

What code you have on SelectedIndexChanged method? You can not put your block of code in another method and call this new method from SelectedIndexChanged and Page_Load?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire selection changed event of your combobox then you can set the SelectedIndex property of combobox to -1 and then set it to the value you want(lets say 0) at page load. This will make sure that SelectedIndexChanged event is fired.